# Sublime - CSS - how to auto add .class for each section in the whole code?

Tags: css, sublimetext2

I wonder if there is any way to auto add class name (e.g. ".header") before each section in CSS code using Sublime?

Example:

```
ul {
    ...;
}
a {
    ...;
}
h1 {
    ...;
}
```

Transform this to:

```
.header ul {
    ...;
}
.header a {
    ...;
}
.header h1 {
    ...;
}
```

Kindly help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only a few instances where you want to apply this change, I'd recommend holding down ctrl & clicking on each location, this'll provide you with multiple carets that all respond to the same input, so you can type `.header` and all locations selected will be affected.

Or you could use find & replace with some regex to do it for you, for example

Find: `^([a-z0-9]{1,} \{)`

Replace with: `.header \1`

This'll match any element selectors such as h1, a, p, li etc... followed by a space and {, and precede them with ".header"

Answer (score 1):

1) ctrl + f / cmd + f

2) check 'regular expression'

3) enter ^[a-z0-9]* {

4) find all

5) replace